# True if for every true value of a fact another fact is also true

Tags: prolog

I tried this as `hello`, but I think it doesn't work.

```
kng_bck(1).
kng_bck(2).
kng_bck(3).

:- dynamic(p/1).

hello :- kng_bck(X), p(X).

% true if p(1). p(2). and p(3). are all defined, 
% that is for every true value of kng_bck(X), p(X) is
also true.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the following definition of `hello` instead:

```
hello :- \+ (kng_bck(X), \+ p(X)).
```

The following query should then return true:

```
?- assert(p(1)), assert(p(2)), assert(p(3)), hello.
```

[\+/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=%5C%2B/1) is true when the goal cannot be proven, so this definition of `hello` is checking there is *not* a situation where "`kng_bck(X)` and *not* `p(X)`".

---

**Update based on feedback in comments:**

You can also achieve this by using [forall/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=forall/2). Example:

```
?- assert(p(1)), assert(p(2)), assert(p(3)), forall(kng_bck(X), p(X)).
```

Comment: I think there is also forall, which kind of solved my problem, can you include that in your answer as well.